# Frea and her dad are trying to kill me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So Frea and her dad are trying to kill me. I accidentally killed the people who were praising the rock because I was really confused and didn't fully catch what I had to do. So I used the scream and now I have to fight a lurker which is kind of impossible for me to do alone. So I went to Frea's village and then she tried to kill me too. I don't know what to do and I'm getting really frustrated because I know that after killing the lurker I have to talk to her dad, but that's going to be really hard because he's really trying to kill me.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much guys! <3

Comment: you should accept the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

Usually the best thing to do in such a scenario is just reload to an old save file or wait. I think it is usually a an in-game week and then everything should turn to normal.

Comment: It's fixed! Thank you so much guys! <3